# Python QuickBase API Help

Tags: python, xml, api, post, quickbase

Hey,  I'm having some trouble using the QuickBase API from Python.  From the QuickBase guide, there are two methods of hitting the API: POST and GET.  I can handle the GET calls, but some API methods require XML to be sent over POST.  The link to the documentation is here: http://member.developer.intuit.com/MyIDN/technical_resources/quickbase/framework/httpapiref/HTML_API_Programmers_Guide.htm

I guess I don't quite understand how to pack the XML payload into the POST request from python.  Using the urllib.urlencode method, as well as any other way I've created POST requests requires a key-value type data structure, where all I have here is a string.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an example of one of your strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  For some reason The data I was sending in my POST needed to have a .strip() placed after it.